# How to log mysql errors from wordpress core?

Tags: mysql, errors

I am developing a wordpress site and I would like to be able to log and handle mysql errors from wordpress core.

My site has a mix of wordpress pages and posts + a few php pages that run under the wordpress engine. I configured the php.ini to prepend a php file to all php scripts with the error handling functions. They are working fine to catch php errors both in the wordpress core and in my own php scripts.

I also catch all the MySQL errors in my own php scripts. For example, failure to connect to a database, etc.

I would like to be able to also catch, log and process eventual MySQL errors from the wordpress core application.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

I was reading through the codex and I couldn't find an answer

Comment: What are you doing that cannot be done with `$wpdb` or `WP_Query`?

Answer (score 8):

You should be using the [`wpdb` class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) for all your own queries. All core queries also use `wpdb`. See [`wpdb` Show and Hide SQL Errors](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Show_and_Hide_SQL_Errors)

```
<?php $wpdb->show_errors(); ?> 
<?php $wpdb->hide_errors(); ?>
```

> You can also print the error (if any) generated by the most recent query with print_error.

```
<?php $wpdb->print_error(); ?>
```

Also see [SAVEQUERIES constant for `wp-config.php`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Save_queries_for_analysis):

```
define('SAVEQUERIES', true);
```

usage example:

```
<?php
if (current_user_can('administrator')){
    global $wpdb;
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($wpdb->queries);
    echo "</pre>";
}
?>
```

There are also a number of helpful debugging plugins, like Debug Bar & Console. Search the WordPress plugin repository for this and other debugging related plugins.

Comment: no `error_log`?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this:

1. Create a file called `db.php` in `wp-content`. Wordpress will read this file immediately before instantiating the `$wpdb` object.
2. Create a `class` which extends `wpdb`, and overwrite the `print_errors` method to do whatever you want.
3. In the end of that file, instantiate your class, setting it the variable `$wpdb` (eg., `$wpdb = new wpdb2(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);`)
4. Wordpress will now use your `$wpdb` instead.

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
global $wpdb;
echo $wpdb->last_query;
```

as i am working with ajax, this is directly in string form.